# Is it possible to make create form on Index page in rails5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have model Project (:title field), that has_many Todos (:text field and project_id field) . I want to have form, to create this Todos, using my projects_controller index page. I tried to do it like this:
My projects_contoller

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  def update
  end

  def create
    @todo = Todo.create(todo_params)
  end

  def delete
  end

  private

def todo_params
  params.require(:todo).permit(:text, :project_id)
end

end
```

And my projects index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @todo, url: {controller: "projects", action: "create"} do |r| %>
  <%= r.text_field :text %>s
  <%= r.text_field :project_id %>
  <%= r.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But when I run my app I get an error:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

Which says, that I have some problem in

```
<%= form_for @todo, url: {controller: "projects", action: "create"} do |r| %>
```

What should I do, to make it possible? Is it even possible to perform create on index page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem:

As khaled noted - If create the new object in your project index controller method.

```
#projects_controller.rb
def index
  @todo = Todo.new
  @projects = Project.all
end
```

The issue of redirecting to the wrong place is all in your form code.

```
<%= form_for @todo, url: {controller: "projects", action: "create"} do |r| %>
```

This is telling your form action (which you can see in the html if you inspect the form element) -to be action in the projects controller.
Replace this:

```
@todo, url: {controller: "projects", action: "create"}
```

with

```
@todo
```

strictly speaking you don't need the controller and action definition if the object has it's own path in the routing table.  Then make sure the redirect from todo create goes back to the index of projects instead of the index of todos.

```
#todos_controller.rb
def create
  @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @todo.save
      format.html { redirect_to projects_path, notice: 'Todo was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

This will mean that if the request is processed successfully, it will redirect to the projects index.

If it's a json request it will render the show.json.jbuilder.

If it's an unsuccessful html request it will render the app/views/todos/new.html.erb file

This will allow to do display errors to the user and correct any issues with the POST.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to add in your controller index method is:

```
@todo = Todo.new
```

Comment: Oh, that's something! But now I get another error, I think, I declared params wrong or something:
param is missing or the value is empty: todo
  params.require(:todo).permit(:text, :project_id)

Comment: Fixed this problem too, but it still doesn't work. Because when I try to create my Todo, it refers to Projects/create, but not to Todo/create

Answer (score 1):

1. In `projects_controller.rb`

`before_action :initialize_todo, only: [:index]`

`private
 def initialize_todo
   @todo = Todo.new
 end`

2. In `index.html.erb`

`<%= form_for @todo do |r| %>`

Form will redirect to create method inside the todos_controller